# Simple way to fill django form with stored information - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django template that I want to display for the user. Now I am working on an editable version of an html template. I wanted to know if there is a way to prefill a django form with relative information that is grabbed from the database or query set. I know how to display and work with forms, but not prefilling a form with information.

Here is a simple form and queryset.

I want to fill the `UserSettingsTwoForm()` with info from the `currentProfile` queryset.

```
currentProfile = Profile.objects.get(user = currentUser)
userSettingTwo = UserSettingsTwoForm()
parameters = {
  'userSettingTwo':userSettingTwo,
}
return render(request, 'tabs/user_settings.html', parameters)
```

Here is a sample html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Settings</h1>
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ userSettingTwo.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If UserSettingsTwoForm is Profile model form then you can load previous instance by just instance keyword and pass instance to it

```
currentProfile = Profile.objects.get(user = currentUser)
userSettingTwo  = UserSettingsTwoForm(instance=current_profile)
 parameters = {
  'userSettingTwo':userSettingTwo,
}
return render(request, 'tabs/user_settings.html', parameters)
```

Otherwise Use Initial if UserSettingsTwoForm is not profile model form.

```
currentProfile = Profile.objects.get(user = currentUser)
userSettingTwo  = UserSettingsTwoForm(initial = {'form_field': currentProfile.fieldname, 'form_second_field': currentProfile.fieldname})
 parameters = {
  'userSettingTwo':userSettingTwo,
}
return render(request, 'tabs/user_settings.html', parameters)
```

Thats' it.